# Establishing a stable state withing a discrete dynamic model

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-modeling, discrete-calculus

Given the following discrete dynamic model:

$P_0=360$ and $R_0=80$ and $t[0,200]$

$P_t=1,18*P_{t-1}-0,002*R_{t-1}*P_{t-1}$and 
$R_t=0,86*R_{t-1}+0,0004*P_{t-1}*R_{t-1}$

One can rewrite the difference equations as:
$P_t=P_{t-1}+0,18*P_{t-1}-0,002*R_{t-1}*P_{t-1}$ and
$R_t=R_{t-1}-0,14*R_{t-1}+0,0004*P_{t-1}*R_{t-1}$

Reasoning that in a stable situation $P_t=P_{t-1}$ and $R_t=R_{t-1}$ calculate $P_0$ and $R_0$ such that a stable situation is established.

Comment: Do you want to find all initial conditions $R_0$ and $P_0$ which result in a stable solution of the system or to prove that the one you mentioned give a stable solution?

Comment: I wan't to find one initial condition for $R_0$ and $P_0$ which result in a stable solution of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\left(P,R\right)$ with $P,R\neq0$ is a fixed point of the
system. That is, if $P_t=P$ and $R_t=R$, we get $P_{t+1}=P$ and $R_{t+1}=R$ from the equations above.

Then,
$$
P=1.18P-0.002RP
$$
and
$$
R=0.86R+0.0004PR.
$$

Dividing these equations through by $P$ and $R$ respectively yields
$$
1=1.18-0.002R
$$
and
$$
1=0.86+0.0004P.
$$

Solving these equations yields
$$
R=\frac{1.18-1}{0.002}=90
$$
and
$$
P=\frac{1-0.86}{0.0004}=350.
$$

Comment: He is looking for a single initial condition which results in a stable solution. A fixed point satisfies this requirement. Take $R_0=R$ and $P_0=P$.

Comment: I see, you are right. That satisfies the task.

Comment: That solves the problem completely. I would appreciate though if you could describe your method a little more. Thank you.

Comment: It turns out, those are the only initial conditions, since the linearized system at the equilibrium is unstable.

Comment: Where does the $-1$ and $1-$ comes from in the equations?

Comment: @Bright: I have added an extra step. Hopefully this should clear things up.

Comment: It clears things up however I see you're dividing both sides with P when you're trying to derive the formula (take the formula for R as an example), however you've got double P so where did the second P go?

Comment: Divide the first one by $P$ and the second by $R$.

Comment: P/P=(1.18P−0.002RP)/P -> 1=1.18-0.002RP

Comment: No. $P/P=(1.18P−0.002RP)/P \rightarrow 1=1.18-0.002R$

Comment: So here lays the problem. Is there any good book or another source to exercise this type of calculation(rebuilding formulas), that you might recommend?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. All I used was that if there exists a nonzero fixed point it must satisfy the above. Maybe read about fixed points? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)

Comment: It's a great help, thank you.